# Post nuclear apocalypse novel with mutant whales, flower-controlled zombies and possibly a psycho-plague

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, soft-sci-fi

I have a memory of a novel that I did not read, but I stumbled upon it on google a few years back and the synopsis and cover stuck in my memory, so I'd really like to find it again (I stupidly didn't save it at the time).

It was an older novel, probably the 80's, but might have been 70's or early 90's. The cover was black and had a skull on it, a red flower was growing from/in the skull or superimposed behind it. The setting was post nuclear apocalypse america, and the review of the book spoke of there being giant mutant whales that dragged themselves across the desert wasteland, a type of plant that could grow inside corpses and control them (I think the end-point of that was a red flower blooming from the head), and if I'm not mistaken there existed some sort of plague that turned people crazy (the term psycho-plague has stuck in my mind, but I can't find anything when googling it).

Anyone know what novel I'm talking about?

Comment: Was it a plant or a fungus?

Comment: @DavidW I'm sure there were flowers involved, so it should be a type of plant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly *[Tight Little Stitches in a Dead Man's Back](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1561465461)* by Joe Lansdale (1992). From [this review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3E19Y1U9RD79T/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1561465461) (bolding mine):

[image: Front cover, featuring a rose]

> The narrator of the story helped to create the Big One. And whaddyaknow? **The Big One gets dropped**. He escapes with his wife to an underground bunker, but leaves his daughter to cook outdoors. She blames him. He blames himself. The bunker, home to 1100 other creators, is Mad Max meets Lord of the Flies and nobody wants to be there. His wife passes the time telling him how much she hates him and tattooing anyone who wants one with a homemade kit. Twenty years later, a group of them decide to take their chances up top. They find a very changed world where **whales prowl the dry bed of the Pacific ocean** and **roses are predatory**. The narrator and his wife find a lighthouse and decide to hole up. She starts tattooing the face of their dead daughter on his back. Day after day, it becomes more clear, until his daughter comes alive and brings the weight of the world on his back, just as his wife is invaded by the roses.

You can read it online [here](https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/tight-little-stitches-in-a-dead-mans-back/). An excerpt about the roses taking over human corpses:

> Thick vines sprouted little, thorny vines, and these moved up the bank and touched the corpses. Then, with a lashing motion, the thorns tore into the flesh, and the vines, like snakes, slithered through the wounds and inside. Secreting a dissolving fluid that turned the innards to the consistency of watery oatmeal, they slurped up the mess, and the vines grew and grew at amazing speed, moved and coiled throughout the bodies, replacing nerves and shaping into the symmetry of the muscles they had devoured, and lastly they pushed up through the necks, into the skulls, ate tongues and eyeballs and sucked up the mouse-gray brains like soggy gruel. With an explosion of skull shrapnel, the roses bloomed, their tooth-hard petals expanding into beautiful red and yellow flowers, hunks of human heads dangling from them like shattered watermelon rinds.

I don't see any mention of a psycho-plague, though. Found with a search for  `nuclear apocalypse "mutant whales"`

Comment: That must be the one, I remember having seen that one before. I think I scrambled the memories of this and Transmaniacon, another novel I haven't read. I'll leave this question open until tomorrow and then mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Whew! That's a doozy!